# Can't extract geo keys, longitude/latitude is out of bounds

Tags: mongodb, google-maps, mongoose

Working with MongoDB 2dsphere to store GEOJSON and on certain stores of lat/lng I keep getting the following error:

```
{
  "code": 16755,
  "index": 0,
  "errmsg": "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('586ff135b79aa00b84181bfb'), name: \"Austin\", slug: \"Austin\", description: \"\", twitter: \"\", facebook: \"\", instagram: \"\", author: ObjectId('57b60fed8620b56af460d5c5'), tags: [], created: new Date(1483731253640), location: { address: \"Austin, TX, United States\", coordinates: [ 30.267153, -97.74306079999997 ], type: \"Point\" }, __v: 0 }  longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 30.2672 lat: -97.7431",
  "op": {
    "name": "Austin",
    "slug": "Austin",
    "description": "",
    "twitter": "",
    "facebook": "",
    "instagram": "",
    "author": "57b60fed8620b56af460d5c5",
    "_id": "586ff135b79aa00b84181bfb",
    "tags": [

    ],
    "created": "2017-01-06T19:34:13.640Z",
    "location": {
      "address": "Austin, TX, United States",
      "coordinates": [
        30.267153,
        -97.74306079999997
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't like some lat/lng coordinates.

Here is my schema for the location field:

```
  location: {
    type: { type: String, default: 'Point' },
    coordinates: [Number],
    address: String
  },
```

and it's indexed as `2dsphere`:

`storeSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });`

The only weird thing I can see is that the error message:

`longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 30.2672 lat: -97.7431",`

the lat/lng are shortened from what I inputted - not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I just started to get this problem when I upgraded from Node 4.2.2 to 7.6.0.  I have yet to resolve it.  Suggestions that the lng, lat are swapped, if true will be a pain in the a** to fix.  I hope there is a way to set that up in the index.

Comment: I figured out a way to fix this.  See my response.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Oh wow - I'm not sure who decided this but Mongodb expects you to store as `[lng, lat]`, not `[lat,lng]` like everything else in this world.

:|

Comment: Take a look at my comment on how to fix this without having to reverse the sequence.

Comment: `[lng, lat]` ordering is standard for GeoJSON. Generally its more intuitive since `lng` corresponds to `x` and `lat` corresponds to `y` in 2d coordinates

Comment: And lat and long should not be in the string format (php)

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I fixed the issue without having to swap the `[lat,lng]` sequence.

Somewhere in your code you are making a call to `ensureIndex`.  Instead of calling (as I was previously doing) ...

```
collection.ensureIndex({ "location": "2dsphere" });
```

Use the following instead ...

```
collection.ensureIndex({ "location.coordinates":"2d"});
```

This completely got rid of the error at runtime and no massive refactor of data was needed.